# How to style a reusable component including two divs, only for one of two parent components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have two different components that they look like columns (**QuantityComponent** and **CalendarViewComponent**) and they will store different data, but they will have inside (one each) a horizontal line that moves when the time change (**GreenCurrentTimeLine component**), as the same reusable component. Now the greenLine  is a single component and has one dot at the beginning, but I want that dot only for the **QuantityComponent** and not present for the **CalendarViewComponent**. The **GreenCurrentTimeLine component** is divided by two styledComponents named: `GreenLine` and `Dot`. Now the question, considering the code below:

```
const GreenCurrentTimeLine = ({ index, hours, minutes }) => {
  // consts
  const ratio = minutes / 60; 
  const topValue = 54 * ratio; // 54 in the height of the GreenLine Div
  return (
    <>
      {index === hours && (
        <GreenLine
          index={index}
          hours={hours}
          minutes={minutes}
          style={{
            top: `${topValue}px`,
          }}
        >
          <Dot></Dot>
        </GreenLine>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
const GreenLine = styled.div`
  background-color: #02b396;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  z-index: 98;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;
const Dot = styled.div`
  background-color: #02b396;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
  left: -1px;
`;
```

How do I say, use the  `<Dot></Dot>` styledComponent only when the parent component, in this case **QuantityComponent** is present and not for **CalendarViewComponent**? I also thought to go to the say something in the **CalendarViewComponent** and apply the style of the **GreenCurrentTimeLine** but without `<Dot></Dot>` but I am not sure how to tackle this. The current view of my page is this: [image]

And what I want is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since your components **QuantityComponent** and **CalendarViewComponent** both contain **GreenCurrentTimeLine**, you could possibly add a prop to your **GreenCurrentTimeLine** to take a boolean showDot and you could dynamically display or hide the **Dot** component like this

```
{ showDot && <Dot/>}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lamy,  I am not sure how and where would I put the showDot. Should that be in the QuantityComponentas a prop? and i should put there a useState with initial value as true? and then the boolean in the GreenCurrentTimeLine? if this is the case, how would I combine the boolean already presen ?: 


{index === hours && (
        <GreenLine
          style={{
            top: `${topValue}px`,
          }}
        >

Comment: I might not have understood your structure correctly, but I was thinking in **QuantityComponent** you call **Dot** with `<Dot index={} hours={} minutes={} showDot=true` and in **CalendarComponen** your would set showDot to false instead. Is this applicable to your structure?

Comment: What i did is passing on the main component **(TimeLineComponent)** _const [showDot, setShowDot] = useState(true);_ then I passed in **quantityComponent** --> **showDot={showDot}** and in **CalendarViewComponent** -->  **showDot={setShowDot(false)}** then the props went to **GreenCurrentTimeLine**  as follow ` return (
    <>
      {index === hours && (
        <GreenLine
          style={{
            top: `${topValue}px`,
          }}
        >
          {showDot && <Dot></Dot>}
        </GreenLine>
      )}
    </>
  );
};`

Comment: But in this way I get the error: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok I removed the state and it worked:) thanks a lot Lamy